# Monkey patching with mock in before block

Tags: ruby, rspec

Here's what ended up working:

```
# lib file
module SlackWrapper
  class << self
    def client
      @client ||= ::Slack::Web::Client.new
    end
  end
end

describe SlackWrapper do
  # test file
  before :each do
    $mock_client = double("slack client").tap do |mock|
      allow(mock).to receive(:channels_info) { channel_info }
    end

    module SlackWrapper
      class << self
        def client
          $mock_client
        end
      end
    end
  end

  describe "#should_reply?" do
    describe "while channel is paused" do
      it "is falsey" do
        SlackWrapper.pause_channel message.channel

        expect(
          SlackWrapper.should_reply? message
        ).to be_falsey
      end
    end

    describe "while channel is not paused" do
      it "is truthy" do
        expect(
          SlackWrapper.should_reply? message
        ).to be_truthy
      end
    end
  end
end
```

This *definitely* does not feel right. However, leaving `$mock_client` as a local var gives me `undefined local variable` when tests are run, and moving the `double...` code into the monkeypatch gives `undefined method`. And of course, monkeypatching.

What's the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just [stub](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/configuring-responses/returning-a-value) the `new` method for a test block or entire spec file:

```
# test file

# you could also create a class double if you need its methods:
# https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-9/docs/verifying-doubles/using-a-class-double
let(:slack_client) { double("slack client") }

before(:each) do
  allow(::Slack::Web::Client).to receive(:new).and_return(slack_client)
end

# simple example:
it "checks slack client method to be a double" do
  expect(SlackWrapper.client).to be(slack_client)
end
```

Comment: I like the idea of doing the stub to the Slack client.new, but this doesn't seem to work for multiple examples:  `#<Double "slack client"> was originally created in one example but has leaked into another example and can no longer be used. rspec-mocks' doubles are designed to only last for one example, and you need to create a new one in each example you wish to use it for.`

Comment: Did you create that globally? Can you show the tests that you wrote around the suggestion?

Comment: Added test cases to original question.

Comment: Interesting. Poked around, removing the `||` in the `||=` in the `SlackWrapper` resolved it. Which... makes sense.

Comment: Found it :) `before( :each ){ allow(SlackWrapper).to receive(:client).and_return(slack_client) }`

Comment: @Narfanator damn, saved me hours; thxs